# HttpURLConnection getInputStream to read page, and then make POST request

Tags: java, post, cookies, httpurlconnection

I trying to get page (HTML), read special token from it (it's different each time), and then send POST request, but that give me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in progress`

```
    final URL url = new URL("<...>");
    String token = null;
    final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try (final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())) {
        try (final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.contains("__token")) {
                    token = str.replace("<...>", "").replace("<...>", "");
                    System.out.println(token);
                    break;
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }
        isr.close();
    }
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    try (final DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
        final String params = getParams("par1", "par2", token);
        wr.writeBytes(params);
        wr.flush(); wr.close();
        final int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + params);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        try (final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }
```

And this same if I try get this token from cookie:

`final String token=con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie").replace("__Token=", "").replace("; path=/; HttpOnly", "");`

How to do that properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation of `HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) says:

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but
>   the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be
>   transparently shared by other instances.

This means that you cannot create a new (POST) request on the same `HttpURLConnection` object. And indeed, you get an `IllegalStateException` from it.

So you should remove the `final` modifier from the definition of `con`, and then, after finishing with the processing of the output of the original (GET) request, create another connection:

```
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Only then, you can continue with constructing your POST request.

---

A little note: you use try-with-resources, so you don't need to explicitly close your streams. Also, you don't need two `try` blocks. In fact, you don't need to keep a reference to the `InputStreamReader`, as `BufferedReader.close()` also closes the underlying `Reader`, which also closes the underlying `InputStream`.

Comment: ok, thanks, about note: I added that code to be sure that this error isn't about open streams.